# Why are the colors below my forms overlapping in materialize.css?

Tags: html, css, materialize

In materialize.css, we can add form validation using the `.validate` class. The default behavior is to underline with green if validation passes, and with red if it fails. In my stylesheet I'm also using:

```
input:focus
{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #03a9f4 !important;
}
```

to change the underline color to light blue when entering information into the form. However, materialize's default behavior and my manually set color conflict, resulting in the following when I'm entering information after a form failure:

[image]

This error also occurs when validation is successful (although it's a bit more subtle due to less contrast between these colors):

[image]

Is there a workaround for this? The HTML in my `<body>` tags used for these forms can be found below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input placeholder="Email" id="emailInput" type="email"
                   class="center-align validate">
            <span class="helper-text" data-error="Please enter a valid email"</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input placeholder="Password" id="passInput" type="password"
                   class="center-align validate">
            <span class="helper-text" data-error="Password cannot be blank"</span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Verify how _materialize.css_ is setting the underline. My guess is that they're not using `border-bottom` and/or applying it to a different element than `input`. You're either adding additional styling instead of overriding it or not properly overriding it. Use your browser's dev tools to inspect the element and find out what style properties _materialize.css_ is using to create the bottom border.

Comment: Also, I suggest using the same CSS selector that _materialize.css_ is using to override their colors instead of using a selector with lower specificity and `!important` (like your example).

Comment: I did what you suggested and used the debugger tool to look at the CSS of the element. I wasn't aware I could even do this so thank you for the suggestion. It turns out there is a `box-shadow` selector which I did not account for. Simply adding `box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #03a9f4 !important;` solved my issue. I'm still not quite sure why I need `!important`, but at least my issue is resolved.

Comment: The reason you need `!important` is because, as my previous comment suggested, the specificity of your CSS selector `input:focus` is not as high as the selector that _materialize.css_ is using. Specificity is a matrix, sort of like a score but not quite. The more parts and/or types of those parts you have in a CSS selector, the higher the specificity will be. Higher specificity rules win out over lower specificity selectors. A single ID selector, `#my-id` has a specificity of `0 1 0 0`. A single Class selector `.my-class` has a specificity of `0 0 1 0`.

Comment: Because specificity is a matrix, a single ID selector will outweigh a selector with 500 class selectors in it. [Here is a helpful site](https://specificity.keegan.st/) to teach and calculate those CSS selectors.

Comment: Gotcha; that makes a bit more sense. I'll look more into it. Thank you!